# App not launching from document in iCloud Drive

Tags: ios, icloud

My app works fine with iCloud, at least in terms of the metadataQuery locating documents in my app's container. I can open and save those documents and see them in iCloud Drive both in iOS 10.x and 11 (through the Files app).

But, when viewing them in iCloud Drive, tapping them does not launch my app, but rather displays a view that identifies the document (accurately) as a MyApp document. If I tap a Pages document, though, Pages is launched and the document opened.

What am I missing? Have I not set a preference properly?

Further, in iOS 11, if I Share->Add People, my document sends properly to the  other iOS 11 device and the message that's sent uses my icon and identifies it as a MyApp document. But tapping that sharing message (in Messages) asks to open the document in Files rather than in MyApp, and does not place the file in the MyApp container, but one level higher where metadataQuery doesn't find it. The same sequence with a Pages document opens Pages and puts the doc into the Pages container. Again, Files is accurately showing my document's icon and identifying it as a MyApp document, but seemingly not connecting that to my app.

Does the explanation make sense? Any idea what I've not done right or am not understanding? Thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 2):

Found the secret. The plist needs a property that allows it to receive a request to open the document. That property is `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace` and it's a Boolean that defaults to NO but should be set to YES for the appropriate `AppDelegate` functions to be called. When I added that (I found it in the sample app ShapeEdit), tapping my app's doc in iCloud Drive launched the app and called the function with my code to open the doc.